# WARN: Ionic Native: tried calling Sim.requestReadPermission, but the Sim plugin is not installed

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am using ionic 3 and making a build for iOS. facing issue => 
**WARN: Ionic Native: tried calling Sim.requestReadPermission, but the Sim plugin is not installed.**

[Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/sim/) has written that ionic-sim plugin supported to the iOS and Android both, but I am facing this issue, attached screen sort below.

[image]

I have used these plugins many times but no progress.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sim

npm install --save @ionic-native/sim@4
```

this is the code that I am using.

```
    getMobileNumber() {
        this.sim.hasReadPermission().then((info) => {
            if(info) {
                this.showMobileNumber();
            } else {
                this.sim.requestReadPermission().then(() => {
                    this.showMobileNumber();
                },(e) => {
                    console.log('Permission denied')
                });
            }
        }, (Error) => {
            console.log(Error)
        });
    }

    showMobileNumber() {
        this.sim.getSimInfo().then((info) => {
            this.showModal(info)
        },(err) => {
            console.log('Unable to get sim info: ', err)
        });
    }

    showModal(info) {
        let contactModal = this.modalCtrl.create(MobilenumberComponent, {
            item: info,
            country: this.acc.countrycode
        });
        contactModal.present();

        contactModal.onWillDismiss(data => {
            if(!!data){ this.acc.phone = parseInt(data) }
        })
    }
```

Comment: same issues i am getting for udid plugin and i tried it with platform ready still facing issue .